# How to pull the total balance on an SPL token for a wallet address in solana (python)

Tags: python, solana

I'm looking to get the token balance for an SPL token in solana based on the:

- Wallet address of the token holder
- The token address

How can I do this?

I thought it would be something like:

```py
import requests
import os

url = os.getenv("SOLANA_RPC_URL")

MY_WALLET_ADDRESS = "XXXXX"
MY_TOKEN_ADDRESS = "XXX"
MINTER = "XXXX"
TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID = "TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb"

payload = {
    "id": 1,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "getTokenAccountsByOwner",
    "params": [
        MY_WALLET,
        {"programId": TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID},
        {"encoding": "jsonParsed"},
    ],
}
headers = {"accept": "application/json", "content-type": "application/json"}

response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

But I keep getting a blank response for what seems to be valid addresses:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"context":{"apiVersion":"1.13.5","slot":176104484},"value":[]},"id":1}
```

I'm using [alchemy](https://www.alchemy.com/) as my node for Solana.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Summary

You can get a wallet's token balances by calling `getTokenAccountsByOwner`.

It takes the following parameters:

- `Pubkey`: Your wallet address
- `dict`: `{"mint": TOKEN_ADDRESS}` where `TOKEN_ADDRESS` is the address of the SPL token you want.

The `dict` can optionally be: "Pubkey of the Token program that owns the accounts" - which I don't understand what that means yet.

## Code

```py
MY_WALLET = "XXXXXX"
MY_TOKEN = "XXXX"

url = os.getenv("SOLANA_RPC_URL")
headers = {"accept": "application/json", "content-type": "application/json"}

payload = {
    "id": 1,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "getTokenAccountsByOwner",
    "params": [
        MY_WALLET,
        {"mint": MY_TOKEN},
        {"encoding": "jsonParsed"},
    ],
}
response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
print(
    response.json()["result"]["value"][0]["account"]["data"]["parsed"]["info"][
        "tokenAmount"
    ]["uiAmount"]
)
```